# Route URI to Different Classes Based On Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I would like to route the same URI to two different classes based on whether the HTTP method is GET or POST. I tried doing this with `RouteAttribute`, but neither route works. If I remove one, the other works. If I put the methods in the same class, it also works. I've also tried `RouteAttribute` + `HttpGetAttribute` and `RouteAttribute` + `HttpPostAttribute`. Is there any way to split the methods into two different classes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with an [`HttpMethodConstraint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.httpmethodconstraint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the route declaration, the code will be something like that:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "route for the GET verb",
    "url",
    new { controller = "controller", action = "action" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "route for POST verb",
    "url",
    new { controller = "other controller", action = "other action" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
);
```